# onOptionsItemSelected() gets called twice on Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

On my main `FragmentActivity` I start the `Fragments` I need, which handle the `ActionBar`. The problem is, that when I click an action item, the `onOptionsItemSelected()` method gets called twice. On that method, I set up and open an `AlertDialog`, which gets opened twice.

Full source: https://github.com/zyngawow/ShoppingList/tree/master/Shopping%20List/src/main/java/com/darkraven/shoppinglist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return true on `onOptionsItemSelected`.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot since I couldn't use the `getChildFragmentManager` because of the `getActivity().onBackPressed()` method.